# Is it better to use a custom Java object or to use a HashMaps to store data

Tags: java

Lets say we have a bunch of data (temp,wind,pressure) that ultimately comes in as a number of float arrays. 
For example:

```
float[] temp = //get after performing some processing (takes time)
float[] wind =
```

Say we want to store these values in memory for different hours of the day. Is it better to put these on a HashMap like:

```
HashMap maphr1 = new HashMap();
maphr1.put("temp",temp);
maphr1.put("wind",wind);
...
```

Or is it better to create a Java object like:

```
public class HourData(){

  private float[] temp,wind,pressure;

  //getters and setters for above!

}
...
// use it like this
HourData hr1 = new HourData();
hr1.setTemp(temp);
hr1.setWind(wind);
```

Out of these two approaches which is better in terms of performance, readability, good OOP practice etc

Comment: First thing you should worry about is whether or not it works for yourself. Don't let someone else decide what "Good OOP Practice" is to you.

Comment: @Timbits I respectfully disagree.  Especially for someone who is just starting to learn OOP, you're much better off following rigid best practices than doing your own thing.  As with most disciplines, you should only be breaking best practices after you've already mastered them. :)

Answer (score 6):

You're best off having an `HourData` class that stores a **single** set of temperature, wind, and pressure values, like this:

```
public class HourData {
    private float temp, wind, pressure;
    // Getters and setters for the above fields
}
```

If you need to store more than one set of values, you can use an array, or a collection of `HourData` objects.  For example:

```
HourData[] hourDataArray = new HourData[10000];
```

This is ultimately much more flexible, performant, and intuitive to use than putting storing the arrays of data in your HourData class.

**Flexibility**

I say that this approach is more flexible because it leaves the choice of what kind of collection implementation to use (e.g. `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc.) to users of the `HourData` class.  Moreover, if he/she wishes to deal just with a single set of values, this approach doesn't force them to deal with an array or collection.

**Performance**

Suppose you have a list of `HourData` instances.  If you used three float arrays in the way that you described, then accessing the i'th `temp`, `wind`, and `pressure` values may cause three separate [pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_%28computer_memory%29) to be accessed in memory.  This happens because all of the `temp` values will be stored contiguously, followed by all of the `wind` values, followed by all of the `pressure` values.  If you use a class to group these values together, then accessing the i'th `temp`, `wind`, and `pressure` values will be faster because they will all be stored adjacent to each other in memory.

**Intuitive**

If you use a `HashMap`, anyone who needs to access any of the fields will have to know the field names in advance.  `HashMap` objects are better suited to key/value pairs where the keys are not known at compile time. Using an `HourData` class that contains clearly defined fields, one only needs to look at the class API to know that `HourData` contains values for `temp`, `wind`, and `pressure`.

Also, getter and setter methods for array fields can be confusing.  What if I just want to add a single set of `temp`, `wind`, and `pressure` values to the list?  Do I have to get each of the arrays, and add the new values to the end of them?  This kind of confusion is easily avoided by using a "wrapper" collection around an `HourData` that deals only with single values.

Comment: Thanks, that's some interesting points about HashMaps. The reason for having array in there is due to size of it. Lets say the temp, wind arrays has about 10,000 values . This will require 10,000 object to be created! I recon this would be too much overhead eh?

Comment: The more values you plan on storing, the more my point about performance becomes relevant. :)  If you want to store 10,000 values you're better off having an array of length 10,000 that stores HourData objects.

Comment: If all of the data arrays are of equal size, then this will do the job.  I think it's pretty hard to estimate performance difference between array of primitives and array of objects. Data allocation algorithms are too complicated to make precise estimation. Anyway, premature optimization is the root of all evil and I don't really think that extra object reference(s) would make too much overhead here. It's better to think about flexibility.

Comment: Hmm I can see the memory access benefit you are pointing out. But let’s say we want to store data for 2 hours. With the array approach, we just create 2 instances of HourData and then add all the 10,000 points to these 2 objects. If we use single Object method we'll have to create 10,000 objects for 1st hr plus another 10,000 for the next. I think Java will run up of heap space as we increase hours, due to the overhead that objects creation causes as oppose to having them just in an array (off course this depend on the hardware we have but I mean in comparison to the two methods).

Comment: @MAKKAM You're absolutely right, it's better not to try to design for better performance until you know what the bottlenecks are.  I just thought I'd mention it in this case because this exact example was outlined to me when I was studying computer science. :)  But yeah, the flexibility alone makes this approach preferable imo.

Comment: @hash With this approach, you're right, you'll have to instantiate 10000 HourData objects. In memory, that works out to having to store and additional 10000 pointers -- which sounds like a lot, but it's not. I believe pointers are 4 bytes (32 bits) on a 32-bit system, so 10000 pointers would work out to be about 0.038MB. Still, it's hard to gauge the exact memory gains/losses without doing some benchmark tests. Perhaps someone else could shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned bunch of data, So I would rather read it as collection of data.

So the answer is , if something already available in Java collection framework out of box , why do you want to write one for you.

You should look at Java collection classes and see which fits your requirement better, whether it is concurrent access, fast retrieve time or fast add time etc etc..

Hope this helps

EDIT----

Adding one more dimension to this.

The type of application you are building also affects your approach.

The above discussion rightly mentions readability, flexibility , performance as driving criteria for your design.

But the **type of application** you are building is also one of the influencing factors.

For example, Lets say you are building a web application.

A Object which is stored in memory for a long time would be either in Application or Session Scope. So you will have to make it immutable by design or use it for thread safe manner.

**The business data which remains same across different implementations should be designed as per OOP or best practices but the infrastructure or Application logic should more be your framework driven.**

I feel what you are talking, like keeping an object for a long time in memory is more a framework driven outlook, hence I suggested use Java Collection and put your business objects inside it. Important points are

1. Concurrent Access Control
2. **Immutable by design**

Comment: My question is not about how the data comes. Ignore the beginning part, I was just settig up a context. What I'm asking is in a situation where you have to store the data is it better to use a HashMap or a Java Object?

Comment: Hmmm..... I read it as if he is creating his own collection object , and I think I was right. Hence said , try to use Java collection object rather than creating your own

Answer (score 0):

For readability i would definately go for a object since it makes more sense. Especially since you store different datacollections like the wind longs have a different meaning as the temp longs.

Besides this you can also store other information like the location and time of your measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you dont have any key to differentiate different instances of the same object. I would create HourData objects and store them in a array list.

Putting data in a contained object always increases the readability.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited and already defined list of parameters then it's better to use the second approach.

1. In terms of performance: you don't need to search for key in hashmap
2. In terms of readability: `data.setTemp(temp)` is better than `map.put("temp", temp)`. One of the benefits of the first approach is that typing errors will be catched during the compilation
3. In terms of good OOP practices: first approach has nothing to do with OOP practices. Using the second approach you can easily change the implementation, add new methods, provide several alternative data object implementations, etc.

But you might want to use collections if you don't know the parameters and if you want to work with uncategorized(extensible) set of parameters.

Comment: Yeah it is a limited defined list of parameter. My initial thought was also to use a Object. Then I discovered HashMaps, thought I will do something fancy with it... but in the end I just got confused LOL. Thanks